# PhpMyadmin | Unable to PUT value for a specific NEW column in the database existing table

Tags: sql, database, laravel, api, phpmyadmin

My present table structure :

[image]

I just added the "product_name" column recently & tried to do the same PUT which has been successfully adding values to the table earlier. For some reason, the newly added product_name field is not getting updated(Rest all columns are getting the values through the same PUT request).

**Am i missing any steps after adding a new column to the existing tables, after which it could accept values via API PUT ?** I added this new column from the Structure tab

```
URL : MY URL
headers: {HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json'},
body: json.encode({id: null, quantity: 1.0, product_id: 113, product_name: cumin, user_id: 72, options: []})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add that column in your model.

```php
protected $fillable = ['product_name', and other columns];
```

or if you don't want to write fillable then simply replace this line with

```php
protected $guarded = [];
```

Answer (score 1):

Please update your $fillable array in your modal.

```
$fillable = ['product_name'];
```